# Angular Fronted make me wait for 20mb to transfer in first load

Tags: angular

I am using MEAN stack for my Full Stack Website. I have developed Front end in Angular5 and deployed on the server. But now it takes too much time to load for the first time as it is downloading near about 20mb.

Here is the screenshot of Network Analyzer on chrome while loading on the first attempt.Can anyone suggest me for any changes to make it faster?.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the 20mb figure from?

Comment: Please check updated one.

Comment: Do you have base64 encoded images in your templates?

Comment: Not yet..working on it.But currently i am having only one image on server to be loaded. Size of that image in near about 1mb.

Comment: So you don't know which asset is leading to the large file size? Check your angular cli file for wat is being included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it all wrong.
To deploy on server we have to build the project via ng biuld --prod(optional) and the place generate dist folder to server and then start server via http-server.

Answer (score 0):

Move larger images to external files instead of embedding them inside the template. Base64 encoding leads to larger file sizes and may delay page loading.

Also make sure you are sending images only in the resolution required for your app. 20 mb is not normal in most cases.

Comment: That is not the case here..JS files are taking too much to load.

Comment: The JS files contain your templates too. They are rendered when your app is loaded.

Comment: I haven't included them. Is there any way to compress them ??

Comment: The templates are your html files. They won't account for more than a few KBs. It will be images or other binary assets that are leading to such a large file size. Go through your project files and libraries to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's we will send file object instance of the base64 value.

Comment: can you explain more about your answer ?